# Aren't ruby Queues thread safe why is the queue not synchronizing?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to create many threads and return the result in a data structure and I read that `Queue` is thread-safe, but when I run the code it doesn't produce the expected result.

```
require 'thread'

class ThreadsTest
  queue = Queue.new
  threads = []
  for i in 1..10
    threads << Thread.new do 
      queue << i
    end
  end

  threads.each { |t| t.join }

  for i in 1..10
    puts queue.pop()
  end
end
```

The code prints: (always a little different)

```
4
4
4
4
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

I was expecting the numbers 1 through 10.

I have tried to `synchronize` it manually to no avail:

```
  mutex = Mutex.new
  for i in 1..10
    threads << Thread.new do 
      mutex.synchronize do
        queue << i
      end
    end
  end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: BTW, it's strange to put such code right into the `class` block. You should wrap it in a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Queue` is thread-safe but your code is not. Just like variable `queue`, variable `i` is shared across your threads, so the threads refer to the same variable while it is being changed in the loop.

To fix it, you can pass the variable to `Thread.new`, which turns it into a thread-local variable:

```
threads << Thread.new(i) do |i|
  queue << i
end
```

The `i` within the block shadows the outer `i`, because they have the same name. You can use another name (e.g. `|thread_i|`) if you need both.

Output:

```
3
2
10
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
```